# Variant of greedy algorithm for vertex cover

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, approximation, vertex-cover

Does the following approximation algorithm for vertex cover also have an approximation ratio of 2? Why? Why not?

Input: $G = (V,E)$

1. Set $C \gets \emptyset$ and $E' \gets E$.
2. **while** $E' \neq \emptyset$ **do**:

   - Pick any edge $(u,v) \in E'$.
   - $C \gets C \cup \{u\}$.
   - Remove from $E'$ all edges incident to $u$.
3. **return** $C$.

Comment: Welcome! As the question asker, you can upvote and/or accept an answer. If you find it helpful, please upvote. If it is the best answer that solves your problem, accept it. That is the basic protocol. Have you checked [what to do when someone answers?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). (This comment will be deleted upon feedback)

Comment: You do not have enough reputation to upvote, yet. However, you can accept an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is a terrible algorithm. Consider a star graph: the vertices are $x,y_1,\ldots,y_n$, and the edges are $(x,y_1),\ldots,(x,y_n)$. Your algorithm goes over the edges in an arbitrary order, and always picks the $y$ vertices. It ends up with $n$ vertices rather than the optimal $1$ vertex solution.